# Get Windows ping and ipconfig tools

Tags: windows, command-line, ping, ipconfig

For some reason, my Windows 7 computer does not recognise the cmd.exe tools `ping` and `ipconfig`. I have tried to download them from the web, but I can only find tools that do similar stuff; not the official `ping` and `ipconfig`.

Where can I get `ping` and `ipconfig` for my Windows 7? What could have caused those networking tools to not be part of my Windows 7? (Other tools I have tried are available.)

Comment: Are you sure they're not there?  This could just be a path issue.  The binaries should both be in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, check if your environment variables (can use `set` from cmd) contains a `PATH` variable with value `C:\Windows\system32`

This is the place ping.exe is in.

You an check if you can call `C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe` assuming C:\Windows is your windows installation directory.

Secondly, you can try running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated `cmd` (running as administrator).

Comment: Ok. I have `PING.EXE` inside `C:\Windows\system32`. I've now added that to path, relaunched cmd.exe, and it still does not work.

Comment: when you type `set` you see the path there ? after restart of cmd.exe

Comment: Yep, it's there

Comment: And  you get file not found ?

Comment: I get "'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Try to open cmd.exe as admin, then, `set path=%path%;C:\windows\system32` , don't close and try to call ping.
Tell us if that works for you.

Comment: It might not be enough though, you need to set your variable properly. 
use `setx`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6821/discussion-between-ofiris-and-justin)

Answer (score 0):

Check your C:\Windows\System32 or whatever drive windows is installed on for ipconfig.exe.  Does it exist? Possibly the account you are using does not have access or there is an issue with the environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

Best guess here (it just happened to me): some recently installed software messed up with the PATH variable and your ping.exe, tracert, etc. are still there in Windows\system32. It's just that you don't run them without specifying the full path.

Just run a search on ping.exe, you should find it easily. If not and they got deleted, go to Control Panel > Programs and features > Turn Windows features on or off and disable, validate, then re-enable it. That should reinstall ping and tracert (as well as a few other standard tools)